# Prerequisites for Fourier Series/Self-Study?

Tags: calculus, fourier-series, fourier-transform

What would be the prerequisites for a typical Introduction to Fourier Series taught at a university. Is an introduction to a rigorous treatment of calculus typically expected or not? So far I've learned the standard Calculus 1-2, Multivariable Calculus, Differential Equations, Linear Algebra, and Proofs. Do I have the necessary background to start self studying Fourier Series. Also, what would one recommend for starting to self study Fourier series?

Comment: my advice : look first at the [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform), prove everything rigorously, then you will be able to prove the Fourier series as some sort of limiting case of the DFT when $N \to \infty$, based on the same concept of unitary operator (but this time on the Hilbert space $L^2([0,1])$, not a finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}$ vector space  anymore)

Comment: Kind of depends on your goals.  If you're just looking to become a user of Fourier transforms ( eg some sort of engineer ), I'd be shocked if there aren't good "practitioner's guide" type texts out there.  I don't know them, though.  Otherwise, you basically know enough to start reading a more mathematical introduction like Stein & Shakarchi ( which I recommend ), but you might be missing some  motivations and intuitions.  I'd say it'd be doable, but hard.

Comment: How would you recommend I fill those gaps in motivations and intuitions

Comment: Stein and Shakarchi should be accessible to someone who has taken a rigorous calculus course at the level of Spivak's *Calculus* or equivalent. For a treatment which is accessible with a less theoretical calculus background, I would recommend Folland's [Fourier Analysis and Its Applications](http://www.amazon.com/Fourier-Analysis-Applications-Applied-Undergraduate/dp/0821847902) Folland does not lack rigor, but rather than getting bogged down in details, he is happy to state the real analysis theorems that he needs, without proof (he provides references for the proofs) and use them as needed.